# Multiple Recordsets Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ado

I have the below SQL Script which is run from Excel VBA using ADO against a SQL Server 2000 database.

The issue I have is that although there is only one SELECT statement in the script, I sometimes receive three recordsets back when executing the .Open method. I say sometimes as on occassion and on other 'parallel' databases I only receive one recordset back.

I know all about the .NextRecordset() method etc. but I am trying to understand why I get three recordsets back some times and other times I only receive one. I'm shortly going to run a SQL trace to see if that throws up any ideas but as usual, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @RunDate VARCHAR(8)

SET @RunDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(d, -1 * 1, GETDATE()), 112)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ActiveOrders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ActiveOrders
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ApplicableOrders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ApplicableOrders
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FilterOut') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FilterOut

/*Temp table created as it has a self-join in the below query */
CREATE TABLE #ActiveOrders(
    order_id VARCHAR(30) 
    , instrument_id VARCHAR(30) 
    , side CHAR(1)
    )

CREATE INDEX idx_ActiveOrders_orderId ON #ActiveOrders(order_id)

/*Build dataset of all orders which have had activity on the run date or are in an Open status. Ignoring Program Trades.*/
INSERT INTO #ActiveOrders 
SELECT o1.order_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        , o1.instrument_id
        , o1.side
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN desk d1 ON d1.desk_id = o1.investment_desk
INNER JOIN (SELECT o0.order_id
            FROM orders o0
            WHERE ((LEFT(o0.added_datetime, 8) = @RunDate
                    OR LEFT(o0.approved_datetime, 8) = @RunDate)
                    OR (LEFT(o0.added_datetime, 8) <= @RunDate
                    AND o0.summary_status IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9))) /*Approved, Assigned, Acknowledged, Working, Partial, WorkingPartial*/
            UNION
            (SELECT r0.order_id
            FROM releases r0
            WHERE LEFT(r0.added_datetime, 8) = @RunDate)
            UNION
            (SELECT e0.order_id
            FROM executions e0
            WHERE LEFT(e0.execution_datetime, 8) = @RunDate
                    OR LEFT(e0.allocated_datetime, 8) = @RunDate)
            ) t1 ON o1.order_id = t1.order_id
WHERE d1.location_id = 'LDEQ'       
        AND o1.summary_status <> 4
        AND o1.list_id IS NULL /*Ignore program trades*/

/*This is now the actual dataset we are interested in.
This is everything which could be a contender for aggregation.*/
CREATE TABLE #ApplicableOrders(
    order_id VARCHAR(30)
    , instrument_id VARCHAR(30)
    , side CHAR(1)
    , approved_datetime DATETIME
    , acknowledged_datetime DATETIME
    , last_allocation_datetime DATETIME
    , latest_status INT
    , merged_orders VARCHAR(500)
    , dealer VARCHAR(100)
    , manager VARCHAR(100)
    , limit_price FLOAT
    , original_qty FLOAT
    , executed_qty FLOAT
    , trader_instruction TEXT
    , dealer_note TEXT
    )

CREATE INDEX idx_ApplicableOrders_orderId ON #ApplicableOrders(order_id)
CREATE INDEX idx_ApplicableOrders_lastAllocation ON #ApplicableOrders(last_allocation_datetime)
CREATE INDEX idx_ApplicableOrders_approved ON #ApplicableOrders(approved_datetime)

/*All orders from #ActiveOrders where there are two or more orders which are for the same instrument and in the same direction.*/
INSERT INTO #ApplicableOrders 
SELECT o.order_id
        , o.instrument_id
        , o.side
        , dbo.mglz_datetime(o.approved_datetime) 
        , dbo.mglz_datetime(o.ack_datetime) 
        , MAX(dbo.mglz_datetime(e.allocated_datetime)) "Last Allocation DateTime"
        , o.summary_status
        , o.merged_orders
        , o.ack_id
        , o.approver_id
        , o.limit_price
        , o.original_qty 
        , o.executed_qty_at
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(900), o.trader_instruction)
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(900), o.dealer_note)
FROM orders o
        INNER JOIN #ActiveOrders t ON o.order_id = t.order_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        INNER JOIN #ActiveOrders s ON s.order_id <> o.order_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                                        AND s.instrument_id = o.instrument_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
                                        AND s.side = o.side COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        LEFT JOIN executions e ON e.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
        , o.instrument_id
        , o.side
        , o.approved_datetime
        , o.ack_datetime
        , o.summary_status
        , o.merged_orders
        , o.ack_id
        , o.approver_id
        , o.limit_price
        , o.original_qty 
        , o.executed_qty_at
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(900), o.trader_instruction)
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(900), o.dealer_note)

/*Filter out any orders where Order2.Approved_Date > Order1.Last_Release_Date AND Order1.Is_Complete
Order1 is defined as the order which was approved first.*/
SELECT t1.*
INTO #FilterOut
FROM #ApplicableOrders t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM
                    (SELECT order2.order_id
                    FROM (SELECT b.order_id
                                    , b.instrument_id
                                    , b.side
                                    , b.approved_datetime
                                    , b.last_allocation_datetime
                                    , b.latest_status
                                    , b.executed_qty
                                    , b.original_qty
                            FROM #ApplicableOrders b
                            WHERE b.approved_datetime = (SELECT MIN(b1.approved_datetime) FirstApproval
                                                        FROM #ApplicableOrders b1
                                                        WHERE b1.instrument_id = b.instrument_id
                                                            AND b1.side = b.side)
                        ) order1
                    INNER JOIN 
                        (SELECT c.order_id
                                , c.instrument_id
                                , c.side
                                , c.approved_datetime
                            FROM #ApplicableOrders c
                            WHERE c.approved_datetime > (SELECT MIN(c1.approved_datetime) FirstApproval
                                                        FROM #ApplicableOrders c1
                                                        WHERE c1.instrument_id = c.instrument_id
                                                            AND c1.side = c.side)
                        ) order2
                    ON order1.instrument_id = order2.instrument_id
                        AND order1.side = order2.side
                        AND order2.approved_datetime > order1.last_allocation_datetime
                        AND (order1.latest_status = 6 OR order1.executed_qty = order1.original_qty)) filter1 
                WHERE t1.order_id = filter1.order_id)

/*Filter out any orders where Order2.Acknowledged_Date > Order1.Last_Allocation_Date.*/
INSERT INTO #FilterOut
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM #ApplicableOrders t1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM
                        (SELECT order2.order_id
                        FROM (SELECT b.order_id
                                    , b.instrument_id
                                    , b.side
                                    , b.approved_datetime
                                    , b.last_allocation_datetime
                            FROM #ApplicableOrders b
                            WHERE b.approved_datetime = (SELECT MIN(b1.approved_datetime) FirstApproval
                                                        FROM #ApplicableOrders b1
                                                        WHERE b1.instrument_id = b.instrument_id
                                                            AND b1.side = b.side)
                            ) order1
                        INNER JOIN 
                            (SELECT c.order_id
                                    , c.instrument_id
                                    , c.side
                                    , c.approved_datetime
                                    , c.acknowledged_datetime
                                FROM #ApplicableOrders c
                                WHERE c.approved_datetime > (SELECT MIN(c1.approved_datetime) FirstApproval
                                                            FROM #ApplicableOrders c1
                                                            WHERE c1.instrument_id = c.instrument_id
                                                                AND c1.side = c.side)
                            ) order2
                        ON order1.instrument_id = order2.instrument_id
                            AND order1.side = order2.side
                            AND order2.acknowledged_datetime > order1.last_allocation_datetime) filter2 
                    WHERE t1.order_id = filter2.order_id)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM #FilterOut a1
                    WHERE a1.order_id = t1.order_id)

/*Filter any 'single' orders. I.e. all 'matching' orders have been excluded so the instrument/direction combination is not applicable for Aggregation.*/
INSERT INTO #FilterOut
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM #ApplicableOrders t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t.instrument_id
                                                            , t.side
                                            FROM #ApplicableOrders t
                                            INNER JOIN #FilterOut a ON t.instrument_id = a.instrument_id 
                                                                                AND t.side = a.side
                                            GROUP BY t.instrument_id
                                                    , t.side
                                            HAVING COUNT(t.instrument_id) > 1) t2 ON t1.instrument_id = t2.instrument_id 
                                                                                        AND t1.side = t2.side
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM #FilterOut a1
                        WHERE a1.order_id = t1.order_id)

/*Final Report*/
/*A list of all orders where aggregation could have possibly occurred but didn't.*/
SELECT t1.order_id "Order ID"
        , i.name "Name"
        , t1.side "B/S"
        , userDealer.short_name "Dlr"
        , userManager.short_name "FM"
        , t1.limit_price "Limit"
        , t1.approved_datetime "Order Approved"
        , t1.acknowledged_datetime "Order Acknowledged"
        , t1.last_allocation_datetime "Last Execution"
        , t1.merged_orders "Merged Orders"
        , m.description "Status"
        , t1.dealer_note "Dealer Note"
        , t1.trader_instruction "Trader Instruction"
FROM #ApplicableOrders t1 
    INNER JOIN instrument i ON t1.instrument_id = i.instrument_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    INNER JOIN mnemonics m ON t1.latest_status = m.value AND m.attribute = 'order_summary_status'
    LEFT JOIN users userDealer ON userDealer.user_id = t1.dealer COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    LEFT JOIN users userManager ON userManager.user_id = t1.manager COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM #FilterOut t2 
                    WHERE t1.order_id = t2.order_id)
ORDER BY t1.name
        , t1.side
        , t1.approved_datetime

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ActiveOrders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ActiveOrders
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ApplicableOrders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ApplicableOrders
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FilterOut') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FilterOut
```

Comment: I should just add that when I do receive 3 recordsets back, the first two are in a closed state indicating that there were no records to return.

Comment: After hitting a dead-end with a SQL Trace and playing with the SQL, I think the issue seems to be with the two WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue and thought I would report back. The problem was with NULL values in two of the Aggregation Functions in the script. The reason this only occurred occasionally is because the data was constantly changing.

Although SQL Server handles the issue 'silently' it does produce warnings which ADO sees as recordsets although in my case (might be every case) these recordsets are closed and so impossible to actually see what they contain or what produced them.

Instead of re-writing the SQL script with ISNULL() logic, I have opted simply to include the

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

statement at the top of the script. This prevents the warnings from being reported and thus ADO does not produce these additional, unwanted recordsets.

Disappointed I didn't spot this earlier but at least I've learnt something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add an isotope column (dummy column) to the end of your temp tables so that when you see the three recordsets you can interrogate the columns names to see where they're coming from.   And what happens when you take the SQL from profile and run directly in SSMS?  Do you get just one resultset?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but two of the three recordsets returned are in a Closed state so I can't do anything with them wich is why I have been struggling to identify what is causing them. When run in SSMS, I only appear to get one recordset back. I'm convinced the issue is with the WHERE EXISTS statements (as I have two of them [and they are SELECT statements]) but unfortunately the issue has resolved itself [for now] so I can't prove it. Once I know either way, I will post my results.